# NullPointerException at sessionFactory using spring

Tags: spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I am facing this problem for several days now and tried - in my opinion - everything to find a solution to this. I am completely out of ideas...

Desciption of what the program should do: It should, after entering a username and password, connect to a database and check if the entered username/password is in that database. Due to the NullPointer of **sessionFactory** he never gets into this check.

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at de.mail.HibernateUtil.getSession(HibernateUtil.java:37)
at de.mail.gui.LoginServlet.doPost(LoginServlet.java:56)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

context.xml:

```
    <!-- Component Scans -->
<context:component-scan base-package="de.mail" use-default-filters="false">
    <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Component" />
</context:component-scan>

<!-- Datenbank -->
<bean id="c3p0DataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl"
        value="****" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="1" />
    <property name="properties">
        <props>
            <prop key="user">postgres</prop>
            <prop key="password">****</prop>
            <prop key="characterEncoding">UTF-8</prop>
            <!-- Properties sind nur notwendig, wenn man mal SSL für die DB-Verbindung 
                braucht (auch in der properties entkommentieren) -->
            <!-- <prop key="ssl">${db.ssl}</prop> <prop key="sslfactory">${db.sslfactory}</prop> -->
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
<alias name="c3p0DataSource" alias="dataSource" />

<!-- TransactionManager -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    <property name="nestedTransactionAllowed" value="true" />
</bean>

<!-- SessionFactory -->
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
    destroy-method="destroy">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan">
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="annotatedPackages">
        <list>
            <value>de.mail</value>
            <value>de.mail.data.dao</value>
            <value>de.mail.vo</value>
            <value>de.mail.gui</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>de.mail.data.vo.UserVO</value>
            <value>de.mail.data.vo.FilterVO</value>
            <value>de.mail.data.vo.ResultVO</value>
            <value>de.mail.data.dao.ActionDAO</value>
            <value>de.mail.HibernateUtil</value>
            <value>de.mail.FilterJob</value>
            <value>de.mail.gui.ActionServlet</value>
            <value>de.mail.gui.CreateServlet</value>
            <value>de.mail.gui.DeleteServlet</value>
            <value>de.mail.gui.EditServlet</value>
            <value>de.mail.gui.FormServlet</value>
            <value>de.mail.gui.InitServlet</value>
            <value>de.mail.gui.LoginServlet</value>
            <value>de.mail.gui.LogoutServlet</value>
            <value>de.mail.gui.RegistrationServlet</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

HibernateUtil:

```
public abstract class HibernateUtil extends HttpServlet{

private static final long serialVersionUID = -1850678939342717642L;

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

/**
 * Gibt die derzeitige Session zurück
 * 
 * @return derzeitige Session
 * @throws HibernateException
 */
public Session getSession() {
    /*try {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();          
    } catch (Throwable e){
        System.out.println("---> " + e);

        return null;
    }*/
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
}
```

LoginServlet:

```
@Component
public class LoginServlet extends HibernateUtil {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -776218596462464850L;
private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(LoginServlet.class);
private static final int HEX_FF = 0xFF;

/**
 * Bearbeitet den Loginversuch<br />
 * Es werden die eingegebenen Daten ausgelesen. Aus dem Passwort wird ein Hash-Wert generiert, der mit dem Datenbankeintrag mit dem
 * passenden Usernamen verglichen wird. Stimmt alles &uumlberein wird auf die main.jsp weitergeleitet. Im Fehlerfall wird zur&uumlck auf
 * die login.jsp verwiesen.
 * 
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 * @param response der HttpResponse
 * @param request der HttpRequest
 * @throws ServletException ex
 * @throws IOException ex
 */
@Override
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
protected void doPost(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    if (!"Registrieren".equals(request.getParameter("register"))) {

        final Session session = getSession();

        // Generiert einen HashWert aus dem eingegebenen Passwort
        try {
            final byte[] pwBytes = request.getParameter("password").getBytes();
            final MessageDigest algorithm = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            algorithm.reset();
            algorithm.update(pwBytes);
            final byte[] messageDigest = algorithm.digest();

            final StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();

            for (byte digest : messageDigest) {
                hexString.append(Integer.toHexString(HEX_FF & digest));
            }

            final LoginDAO dao = new LoginDAO();
            final List<UserVO> list = dao.checkLogin(request, session);

            final UserVO userVO = list.get(0);

            if (userVO.getPassword().equals(hexString.toString())) {

                request.getSession().setAttribute("userid", userVO.getId());
                final RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("main.jsp");
                dispatcher.forward(request, response);

            } else {

                final RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp");
                dispatcher.forward(request, response);
            }

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException nsax) {
            LOG.debug("Keine MessageDigestSpi fuer den entsprechenden Alogrithmus gefunden");

        } catch (NullPointerException npx) {
            final RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp");
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);

        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ioobx) {
            final RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp");
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
        }
    } else {
        final RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("register.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }
}

/**
 * Tut nix besonders. Leiet an die doPost-Methode weiter
 * 
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 * @param response der HttpResponse
 * @param request der HttpRequest
 * @throws ServletException ex
 * @throws IOException ex
 */
@Override
protected void doGet(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    doPost(request, response);
}
```

I really don't get the error here. I checked every file, especially the spring context for missing content but found really nothing. I assume that the error is caused by something pretty simple. For me - I am pretty new to spring and hibernate - the error doesn't want to be found.

Comment: You have 2 instances of your servlet 1 managed by spring 1 managed by your web container. The one from the web container is the one actually used but as it isn't under springs control it will not have the dependencies injected. I strongly suggest you ditch the servlet and make it a controller and use Spring's `DispatcherServlet` to invoke it. Also your design is flawed as you should inject the session factory into your dao not your servlet. Not to mention the fact that your dao layer is dependent onto the web layer.

Comment: @M.Deinum This would explain everything! The main reason this issue occures is that it is a 5 year old non-spring-project in which i try to implement spring and update all dependencies. I'm aware that the design isn't the best. The project was build at the beginning of my programmers "career", so the code qualitiy isn't very high. May I ask you to point out the spicific code fragments, which tell you that the project is managed by the web container? Would be great! Thank you so much for the answer!

Comment: You have a `@Component` on your `LoginServlet` which will let it be detected by Spring. However I'm pretty sure you also have a servlet declaration in your web.xml for this `LoginServlet`. This will result in 2 instances one spring managed and one non spring managed. If you want to retrieve the `SessionFactory` do it in the `init` method of your servlet and use the `WebApplicationContextutils` to get the `ApplicationContext` and retrieve it from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `LoginServlet` has a `@Component` annotation which will make it a spring managed bean however there is probably also a servlet declaration in your web.xml. You now have 2 instances of the servlet one managed by spring (and pretty useless as it isn't used otherwise) and an instance managed by the web container, which doesn't do anything with `@Autowired`.

To fix your problem use a dependency lookup instead of trying to do dependency injection. For this use the `init` method of the servlet and simply remove the `HibernateUtil` class and also the `@Component` annotation.

```
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void init() {
        ApplicationContext ctx = WebApplicationContext.getApplicationContext(getServletContext());
        sessionFactory = ctx.getBean(SessionFactory.class);
    }

    protected Session getSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }
    …
}
```

Your `@Transactional` is never going to work as the bean isn't spring managed the annotation is basically doing nothing. You could fix this by wrapping your `doPost` method in a `TransactionTemplate`.

```
<bean id="txTemplate"  class="TransactionTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="transactionManager" />
</bean>
```

Then add a lookup for it in your `init` method

```
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private TransactionTemplate txTemplate;

    public void init() {
        ApplicationContext ctx = WebApplicationContext.getApplicationContext(getServletContext());
        …
        txTemplate = ctx.getBean(TransactionTemplate.class);
    }
```

Rename your original `doPost` method to `doPostInternal` and optionally make it `private` and add the following `doPost` method`

```
protected void doPost(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    txTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult() {
        public void doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionStatus status) {
            doPostInternal(request,response);
        }
    });
}
```

Finally your hibernate configuration is also flawed as you are messing around with the `hibernate.current_session_context_class`. When using spring you should leave this property alone unless you are using JTA. Looking at your configuration you aren't so remove the setting of that property, the current setting breaks proper spring integration with hibernate.

I strongly suggest you take a look at your overall architecture as your current design is flawed imho. You have a dao layer which depends upon the web layer (it has a dependency on the `HttpServletRequest`). You are trying to shoehorn spring into a non spring based application (which you can make work as mentioned above but using spring is easier). Moving the code to a `Controller` and making a proper `LoginDao` would improve your overall architecture. It would also make it easier to test (no more web dependencies).

Comment: I would love to give you 100 rep if I could, man. Thank you for taking the time and explaining this all to me! I will create a new project and use spring properly in it. Maybe we will see us when I have another question related to my "new" project. Thanks again, you're great!

Answer (score 0):

Try to write below code for HibernateUtil

```
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;


    public class HibernateUtil {

        private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

        static {
            try {
                // Create the SessionFactory from standard (hibernate.cfg.xml) 
                // config file.
                sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
            } catch (Throwable ex) {
                // Log the exception. 
                System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
                throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
            }
        }

        public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
            return sessionFactory;
        }
    }
```

Below code will guide you how to use above class

```
HibernateUtil hu= new HibernateUtil();
SessionFactory sessionFactory =hu.getSessionFactory();
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Query q = session.createQuery ("from UserM where userid='"+lf.getUser()+"' and userpass='"+lf.getPassword()+"'");
```

Comment: But that is not what I want. I want spring to initialize the sessionFactory. Otherwise I won't use spring. I can try doing it manually, but this will not solve my original problem.

Comment: I do not have a hibernate.cfg.xml. Hibernate is configured by spring. This code does not help, but thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Try "c3p0DataSource" reference to SessionFactory bean rather than using alias.

Comment: Thanks for your hint but I am using an alias because I had trouble without using it. In some cases this could probably the reason for sessionFactory to be NULL, but not in my case. I appriciate your answer though! :)